# Add HTML tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I got an Javascript code like this:

```
divElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Optie " + inputNumber + ": "));
```

Now I would like to put "Optie " and ": " in h7 tags.

How can i do this?

Comment: @BalaR - I guess so, his title says Javascript

Comment: Yea i do :) Sorry for the confusion :).

Comment: h7 tags?! the range is from 1 to 5!

Comment: What are `h7` tags? You must be new to HTML. @daveoncode, [tags range from `1-6`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements)

Comment: ops! falled in the same error :P 1 to 6... anyway there is not h7 tag :P

Comment: you can declare as much H tags as you want, they just stop generating standard values. Try it for a time :). And its cross browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myHeader = document.createElement("h5");
myHeader.innerHTML = "Optie " + inputNumber + ":";
myHeader; // => <h5>Optie 123:</h5>
```

Answer (score 5):

there is no "h7". Max is H6

<del>newHeadline = document.createNode( 'h6' );
    newHeadline.createTextNode("Optie " + inputNumber + ": ")
    divElement.appendChild( newHeadline );</del>

Sorry, the right code:

```
newHeadline = document.createElement( 'h6' );
text = document.createTextNode("Optie " + "ddd"+ ": ")
divElement.appendChild( newHeadline.appendChild( text ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! Well i know max is H6 normally, but you can define as much H tags as you want just declare them in ur css. But thanks for this answer :D.

Comment: Uhm tried it, but didn't work out that great. tried maerics code and it worked perfectly. But thanks anyway.